# How to get at Apache Wicket PropertyColumn data to dynamically change CSS class based on content?

Tags: css, apache, properties, conditional-statements, wicket

I have an Apache Wicket page that has a DataTable with a column that needs to show the statuses, Red, Yellow, Green.  If the content of the column is Red, I want to change the CSS class to red-status, if yellow yellow-status, else green-status.  I can't seem to get at the data in the way you can from a clickable property column.  How do you get at the data in a PropertyColumn, or is there another way to do this in a DataTable?  Thank you!

UPDATE

Thank you, Martin. Here's what I came up with:

```
@Override
public void populateItem(Item<ICellPopulator<T>> cellItem, String componentId, final IModel<T> rowModel) {
    Label label = new Label(componentId, getDataModel(rowModel));
    cellItem.add(label);
    LOGGER.debug("populateItem: label DefaultModelObject: {}", (String) label.getDefaultModelObject());

    label.add(new AttributeModifier("class", new AbstractReadOnlyModel<String>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        ProcessingTime  processingTime = (ProcessingTime) rowModel.getObject();
        @Override
        public String getObject() {
            String cssClass = null;
            if (StringUtils.equals("Red", processingTime.getStatus())) {
                cssClass = "red-status";
            } else if (StringUtils.equals("Yellow", processingTime.getStatus())) {
                cssClass = "yellow-status";
            } else if (StringUtils.equals("Green", processingTime.getStatus())) {
                cssClass = "green-status";
            } else {
                cssClass = "process-status";
            }
            return cssClass;
        }
    }));
}
```

[image: Table with dynamic css in cells]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing first, look at the populateItem of PropertyColumn, how does the implementation looks like, in Wicket 6 (similar like other versions) it is:

```
public class PropertyColumn<T, S> extends AbstractColumn<T, S> implements IExportableColumn<T, S, Object>
...
    @Override
    public void populateItem(final Item<ICellPopulator<T>> item, final String componentId,
        final IModel<T> rowModel)
    {
        item.add(new Label(componentId, createLabelModel(rowModel)));
    }
...
}
```

You have to modify the inner component that is create as the label of the column.

First method: create your own component (also your component is able to contain its own mechanism of creation css class or style instead of adding an AttributeModifier here):

```
@Override
public void populateItem(final Item<ICellPopulator<T>> item, final String componentId,
    final IModel<T> rowModel)
    {
    super.populateItem(item, componentId, rowModel);
    MarkupContainer c = item.get(componentId);
    c.add(new AttributeModifier("class", new AbstractReadonlyModel<String>() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public String getObject() {
        // some logic how to which css you want to apply
        return "MY-CSS-CLASS";
    }



}));
```

}

or you can let Wicket to create the Label component itself and you just add an AttributeModifier:

```
@Override
public void populateItem(final Item<ICellPopulator<T>> item, final String componentId, final IModel<T> rowModel) 
    {
    super.populateItem(item, componentId, rowModel);
    Label l = new Label(componentId, createLabelModel(rowModel));
    item.add(l);
    l.add(new AttributeModifier("class", new AbstractReadonlyModel<String>() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public String getObject() {
        // some logic how to which css you want to apply
        return "MY-CSS-CLASS";
    }



}));
```

}

**NOTE:** the method 'createLabelModel' is deprecated in Wicket 6, rather to use 'getDataModel' instead.

Comment: Martin, thank you for your suggestions. I tried these and the CSS is getting set for the column, but not the cell.  I tried different approaches but the font color in the CSS is always applied to the entire column.

Comment: If you add some condition to the AttributeModifier you get it. You have the Model of the row that is to be rendered so you can implement something like 'return rowModel.getObject.isMyRow() ? "my-red-css-class" : "default-css-class"';